# does "organic" in "advertising and organic search results" mean smart or intelligently?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

i am learning this [post](https://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2018/01/building-a-distributed-ml-pipeline-part1.html), which says

> As a part of Yelp’s mission to connect people with great local
>   businesses, we help businesses reach potential customers through
>   advertising and organic search results.

an online advertising system is a website shows different advertisements to different users.

the question is, dose "organic" in the post mean that their system is smart enough to know what people accessing their website is interested in?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, "organic" here is being used as a pseudo-technical term, to make the pitch sound more scientific and technically advanced.

I believe that in this sentence "organic search results" means the results returned naturally by the search algorithm, as opposed to results specifically aided for advertising purposes, sometimes called "sponsored results". Note that "organic" is not used in any of the more technical parts of the post, the parts that are not blurbs for Yelp's service.

Since the search algorithm is itself artificial, to call its results 'organic" is perhaps overstatement.